# How do I implement gmail login?

Tags: php, authentication

How do I implement site authentication using gmail, yahoo or facebook IDs (not OpenID login)?

PS: Using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google offers two APIs for login:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html

**EDIT as AuthSub was officially deprecated on April 20, 2012 and will be shut down on April 20, 2015.**

You can use new API.. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Yahoo also offers another one:
http://developer.yahoo.com/auth/